How authentication Laravel Sanctum SPA application with two subdomain
I'm currently working on a Laravel application that consists of two areas: Admin and App. The admin area is built using Inertia.js, and authentication is handled with Sanctum, which is functioning correctly. The app area, on the other hand, utilizes Nuxt 3. My goal is to display content fetched via API from the admin application in the app area. While authentication works well, I encounter a 401 error when attempting to fetch authenticated user data.
Additionally, There is one more issue I'm facing if I'm logged into the admin and trying to login into the app it gives a 305 response on the login request and if I logout from the admin and try to login into the app login is successful but the /api/user response 401 and If I visit the admin area it's showing me authenticated.
The domains for the areas:
Admin: admin.kpowa.dev
App: app.kpowa.dev:80
.env file in the laravel
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="app.kpowa.dev,app.kpowa.dev:80,admin.kpowa.dev"
SESSION_DOMAIN=.kpowa.dev

login function
public function store(LoginRequest $request): JsonResponse|RedirectResponse
    {
        // Check if the request is from an SPA
        if (!EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::fromFrontend($request)) {
            // Handle API authentication
            $validated = $request->validated();

            // Ensure rate limiting
            $request->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

            $user = User::query()->where('username', $validated['username'])->first();

            if (!$user || !Hash::check($validated['password'], $user->password)) {
                RateLimiter::hit($request->throttleKey());
                return response()->json(['' => trans('auth.failed')], 422);
            }

            $token = $user->createToken($request->userAgent())->plainTextToken;

            // Clear rate limiter
            RateLimiter::clear($request->throttleKey());

            return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
        }

        // Handle SPA authentication
        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password') + ['type' => 1];
        if (!$request->header('x-inertia')) {
            $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password') + ['type' => [0, 2, 3]];
        }

        try {
            // Attempt authentication
            $request->authenticate($credentials);

            // Authentication successful, regenerate session
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            if (!$request->header('x-inertia')) {
                return response()->json(['status' => trans('auth.login_success')], 200);
            }

            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        } catch (\Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException | \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e) {
            // Authentication failed, redirect back with error message
            return back()->withErrors(['error' => trans('auth.failed')]);
        }
    }

LoginRequest.php
public function authenticate(array $credentials): void
    {
        $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

        if (! Auth::attempt($credentials, $this->boolean('remember'))) {
            RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'error' => trans('auth.failed'),
            ]);
        }

        RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
    }

Could you assist me in resolving this issue?
I am trying to achive that I can use the admin and app area individually with secure authentication.

To let Laravel recognize allowed domains besides applying middleware you have to configure the following:

SESSION_DOMAIN to be .domain.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS to contain all subdomains
allowed_origins to contain all subdomains (config/cors.php) or just * instead

Also, make sure that origin or referer header is being sent properly from Nuxt.
Sometimes, for local development, it is better to use localhost on different ports to prevent problems with host interferences.
You can also take a look at https://github.com/manchenkoff/nuxt-auth-sanctum, which works well with Nuxt / Laravel Sanctum. There is complete documentation on how to set it up and what changes are expected from the Laravel side. Feel free to raise an issue on GitHub if further help is needed!
